# Hide menu by clicking outside a div or a on mouseout after a certain amount of time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, css

On a web page there are menus and on hovering it sub menus open.All menu and sub menus are made using div and sub menus are hiding using style.display = none;

The problem is once subMenu is opened it does not hide even on mouse-out. It remains open no matter user has clicked somewhere else on the page.

I want to know how can I implement some functionality so that after some time it automatically get disappear or on clicking on rest of the area on page it disappears?

**Note**: mouseout is not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

For `how can I implement some functionality so that after some time it automatically get disappear` use `setTimeout`.

```
var canceled;

$("mymenu").on("focusout", function() {
    canceled = false;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!canceled) {
            // Hide menu
        }
    }, 2000);
});

$("mymenu").on("focusout", function() {
    canceled = true;
});
```

For `or on clicking on rest of the area on page it disappears.` you should bind a `click` event directly on the `document` root:

```
$(document).on("click", function() {
    // hide menu if visible
});
```